# chroma subsampling in opencv imwrite

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, jpeg

I'm using OpenCV to resize a JPG.   Code is like

```
im = cv2.imread(infile)
resized_im = cv2.resize(im, None, None, 0.5, 0.5, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.imwrite(outfile, resized_im)
```

When looking at the resized image I can see the chroma has been downsampled.

```
$ identify -verbose input.jpg | grep samp
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
$ identify -verbose resized.jpg | grep samp
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
```

Is there any way to change this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I worked on Android and tried to reproduce your used case in  Android CV... What I have done is following...

```
Mat tempMat=new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bm, tempMat);
Mat tempMat1 = new Mat(tempMat.rows()/2, tempMat.cols()/2, tempMat.type());
Imgproc.resize(tempMat, tempMat1, new Size(), 0.5, 0.5, Imgproc.INTER_LINEAR);
Utils.matToBitmap(tempMat, bm);
bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempMat1.width(), tempMat1.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(tempMat1, bm);
```

Then I have some code to save both bitmaps to files... I checked the saved files after downloading them from my Android device to Ubuntu desktop...

```
 atul@ubuntu:~/Development/sdk/platform-tools$ ls -l IMG_?.jpg

    -rw-r--r-- 1 atul atul 209336 Feb 13 09:58 IMG_1.jpg
    -rw-r--r-- 1 atul atul  63237 Feb 13 09:58 IMG_2.jpg
 atul@ubuntu:~/Development/sdk/platform-tools$ identify -verbose IMG_1.jpg | grep samp
        jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
 atul@ubuntu:~/Development/sdk/platform-tools$ identify -verbose IMG_2.jpg | grep samp
        jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
```

The only difference in your code and mine are I used new Size() and created the Destination Mat object with half of the size. Can you try the above two things in your code and see if it works...

Just by looking at output you are getting I think its not Chroma but Lumina is getting increased... in YCrCb color space, the first element is Lumina, second is Chroma Red and third is Chroma blue...

There is good article in OpenCV documentation to play around with Y Cr and Cb. Following is the link...

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1.html

I don't think Android CV or C ++ CV or Python CV should make any difference, since all three use s the same underlying native CV code...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks Atul,  I'm trying to get it to stay at 1x1x1 after being transformed.

Comment: Do you mind to send me your image... I was not able to get the image of 1X1X1... Please send me your image file for checking...

Comment: sure,  where should i send it?

Comment: I really don't know how it works in stack overflow...You can send it to my primary email id... Please mark Stack Overflow : in subject line...